# How to get Facebook Ad Manager Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

From where I can get the comments data of posts from Ad Manager? Those posts are not going to page, but I need to retrieve the comments. Is there any way to get the comments from Graph API?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should be able to get a post's comments via Graph API. The comments are edges belonging to a post:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/

Comments on a post are not available in Ads Manager or Power Editor.